# Why does calling make with a shell script target create an executable file?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, gnu-make

I had written a simple shell script (called `test.sh`) to compile a test C++ file using two different compilers (g++ and clang++) and put some `echo` statements in to compare the output. On the command line, I accidentally typed `make test`, even though there was no Makefile in that directory. Instead of complaining about no Makefile or no target defined, it executed the following commands (my system is running the 64-bit Debian stretch OS with GNU Make 4.1 ):

```
user@hostname test_dir$ make test
cat test.sh >test
chmod a+x test
user@hostname test_dir$
```

Curious about that, I made another shell script (`other.sh`) and did the same thing.

> Here is my `other.sh` file:

```
#!/bin/bash

echo ""
echo "This is another test script!"
echo ""
```

> Command line:

```
user@hostname test_dir$ make other
cat other.sh >other
chmod a+x other
user@hostname test_dir$
```

My question is why does `make` automatically create an executable script (without the `.sh` extension) when running the `make` command in the terminal? Is this normal/expected/standard behavior? Can I rely on this behavior on all Linux machines?

---

Side question/note: Is there a list of supported "implicit suffixes" for which `make` will automatically create an executable?

Comment: If you are using gnu-make (which you probably are), you can run `make -d other` to see a verbose list of all the suffixes it will try.

Comment: From my info page: `The default suffix list is: `.out', `.a', `.ln',
`.o', `.c', `.cc', `.C', `.cpp', `.p', `.f', `.F', `.m', `.r', `.y',
`.l', `.ym', `.lm', `.s', `.S', `.mod', `.sym', `.def', `.h', `.info',
`.dvi', `.tex', `.texinfo', `.texi', `.txinfo', `.w', `.ch' `.web',
`.sh', `.elc', `.el'.`

Comment: Whoever decided that a backtick was a good character to put in docs!?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is one of a number of "implicit rules" which are built into Gnu make. (Every make implementation will have some implicit rules, but there is no guarantee that they are the same.)

> 1. Why does make automatically create an executable script without the .sh extension?

There is an old source repository system called [Source Code Control System](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Source_Code_Control_System) (SCCS). Although it no longer has much use, it was once the most common way of maintaining source code repositories. It had the quirk that it did not preserve file permissions, so if you kept an (executable) shell script in SCCS and later checked it out, it would no longer be executable. Gnu make could automatically extract files from an SCCS repository; to compensate for the disappearing executable permission issue, it was common to use the `.sh` extension with shell scripts; `make` could then do a two-step extraction, where it first extracted `foo.sh` from the repository and then copied it to `foo`, adding the executable permission.

> 2. Is this normal/expected/standard behavior? Can I rely on this behavior on all Linux machines?

Linux systems with a development toolset installed tend to use Gnu make, so you should be able to count on this behaviour on Linux systems used for development.

BSD make also comes with a default rule for `.sh`, but it only copies the file; it doesn't change permissions (at least on the bsdmake distribution on my machine). So the behaviour is not universal.

> 3. Is there a list of supported "implicit suffixes" for which make will automatically create an executable?

Yes, there is. You'll find it in the [make manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Catalogue-of-Rules.html#Catalogue-of-Rules):

> The default suffix list is: `.out`, `.a`, `.ln`, `.o`, `.c`, `.cc`, `.C`, `.cpp`, `.p`, `.f`, `.F`, `.m`, `.r`, `.y`, `.l`, `.ym`, `.lm`, `.s`,
>   `.S`, `.mod`, `.sym`, `.def`, `.h`, `.info`, `.dvi`, `.tex`, `.texinfo`, `.texi`, `.txinfo`, `.w`, `.ch`, 
>   `.web`, `.sh`, `.elc`, `.el`.

For a more accurate list of implicit rules, you can use the command

```
make -p -f/dev/null
# or, if you like typing, make --print-data-base -f /dev/null
```

as described in the [make options summary](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Options-Summary.html#Options-Summary).

Answer (score 1):

From the **[`make`](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html)** man page:

> The purpose of the make utility is  to  determine  automatically 
>   which
>          pieces of a large program need to be recompiled, and issue the commands
>          to recompile them.  The manual  describes  the  `GNU`  implementation  of
>          make,  which was written by Richard Stallman and Roland McGrath, and is
>          currently maintained by Paul Smith.   Our  examples  show  `C`  programs,
>          since  they  are most common, but you can use make with any programming
>          language whose compiler can be run with a shell command.  In fact, make
>          is  not limited to programs.  You can use it to describe any task where
>          some files must be updated automatically from others whenever the  others change.

`make` really is more than most people ***make*** it out to be...